# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: with log4j velocity custom layout

Tags: java, layout, log4j, velocity

I am writing a custom layout for log4j appender with velocity, but I am unable to get it to run

the error below:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties     at
>   org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.(RuntimeInstance.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.(VelocityEngine.java:60)
>     at
>   nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.assign1.s06013597.VelocityLayout.(VelocityLayout.java:16)
>     at
>   nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.assign1.s06013597.VelocityLayoutTest.test(VelocityLayoutTest.java:36)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>     ... 27 more

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>assign251_2</groupId>
  <artifactId>s06013597</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>s06013597</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>


<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: This is often a dependency version conflict problem. Can you post your pom.xml, in case it's a Maven project?

Comment: I have run your code on my machine and the test passes... Try to reimport your dependencies, or delete your apache/commons/collections from your .m2 directory and import it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs ok and your test passes on my machine. You should reimport your maven dependencies, and / or delete your apache/commons/collection directory from your .m2 folder.